# Generate M by N matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to generate an M by N matrix where N is the number of multivariate normal random variables with M number of samples. I am trying to generate the matrix such that each column is a unit-variance and correlation between any two columns is Y.

I have tried

```
M = 100
N = 3 
Y = 0.5 
mean = (0,0,0)
cov = np.array([[0.5,0.5,0.5],[0.5,0.5,0.5],[0.5,0.5,0.5]])

np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, (M,N))
```

it returns an np array consisting of M array where each ith array consist of N number of values and they are all the same.

Can anyone advise how to generate an **M by N matrix** such that **each column in a unit variance and correlation between any two columns is Y**, where **N is the number of standard multivariate normal random variable.**

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that I am almost entirely wrong. The reason why your values are not deviating is because you have a correlation value of 1 between your values. As a result, the values no not vary.

Comment: One follow up here:

1) Would this ensure that correlation between each column is 0.5? If yes, how?

Comment: Ah, so it seems like we are having more a math problem here. The covariance matrix measures the covariance between each matrix. Correlation is equal to cov(x,y)/(sd(x) * sd(y)). If we look at the matrix that you gave above, the covariance between each matrix is a half and the variance of each matrix is also a half. As a result, when calculating correlation, the correlation between each variable is 1 which explains why all of the values in your matrix is the same. If you would like to have correlation of 0.5, I would scale the variation values by a factor of sqrt(1/2)